# Alternative to global pooling using tf.reduce_mean?

Tags: python, tensorflow, conv-neural-network

```
output = tf.reduce_mean(net, [1, 2], name='global_pool', keep_dims=False)
```

`net` is of shape (batch_size, height, width, #channels)

Is there any other way to do global pooling and obtain the same result?

Comment: There are possibilities, but should the be more efficient or what's the matter?

Comment: Because i'm using movidius ncs, and i have a problem when converting it to the native graph. That's the reason i need an alternative. Could you suggest me one?

Answer (score 1):

I have one that is computational very complex, but it works:

1. Use `tf.split(..., axis=-1)`
2. Perform `tf.layers.average_pooling2d` for every split and chose the kernel size = tensor size

The second option is:
`tf.keras.layers.GlobalAveragePooling2D`, but I would suggest the use `tf.reduce_mean`under the hood, but dint looked in the source.

Comment: If this answer fits your needs pls mark it as answered or specify your problem further.

Comment: We we don't just use the one provided by tensorflow please? Second, why you use `tf.splot()`?

Comment: Can you please explain why he needs to convert it to a native graph?